# How can I sort an alphanumerical Multidimensional Array in php?

Tags: php, sorting, php-7.0

I have some json filenames in an multidimensional array, created like this: `$files[] = array("name" => $file, "type" => "json")` that I want to **sort ascending** like this:

```
1.File
2.File
3.File
10.File
11.File
```

If I order them using php `sort($files)` function they will be ordered like this:

```
1.File
10.File
11.File
2.File
3.File
```

If however I use `natsort($files)` that quote: *orders alphanumeric strings in the way a human being would ([php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php))*, I get a total mess:

```
3.File
2.File
10.File
1.File
11.File
```

Is there some better approach to order an array using php functions? Or do I have to build a custom sorting function. The server is running PHP 7.0.

Comment: Write custom callback function or [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) , split numeric part from file name, convert to int and use that to sort.

Comment: Am I missing something or does it seem to [work](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd28fd42a6976e31d51683fd9ceedd082ac9cecd)?  the keys simply need to be reset

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62275720/457268

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, I forgot to mention it's an object array. I have updated the question.

Comment: @AlinCrescensCiurea Can you edit my example and share with us with correct data?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini sure. [here it is](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21baad3509d91130a2b024349c0b33f8e0c3401b)

Comment: Where is the object array? `$files` in the question is still a normal php array.

Comment: `sort`ing function __DO NOT__ work with multidimensional arrays. Write your custom sort with `usort` as already mentioned.

Comment: @shingo It's a multidimensional array. Sorry for labeling it incorrectly.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code you are currently using and a sample set of input data

Comment: Also, if the server is still running PHP 7.0, please plan to upgrade it. That branch has left security support three years ago!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use multidimensional array, as you can see PHP have an error (`Array to string conversion`), you need to use `usort` for that task like:

```
$array = array(
    array("name"=>'1.File', "type" => "json"),
    array("name"=>'2.File', "type" => "json"),
    array("name"=>'3.File', "type" => "json"),
    array("name"=>'10.File', "type" => "json"),
    array("name"=>'11.File', "type" => "json"),
    );
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return ($a['name'] > $b['name'])
           ? 1 
           : ($a['name'] < $b['name'])
             ? -1 
             : 0;
});
print_r($array);
```

[Your fiddle edited](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/07f7b1922da16a6dc55e90e1e2fb21194a85b421)

Reference:

- [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

---

As @u_mulder suggest `strnatcasecmp` will improve the code like:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return strnatcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
});
```

Reference:

- [strnatcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcasecmp.php)

Comment: `return strcmp` probably?

Comment: @u_mulder Can you give me an example? Trying gives it to me wrong.

Comment: My mistake, just `return strnatcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']);`

Comment: @u_mulder Thanks for the advice, I never stop learning :)

Comment: Thank you, @SimoneRossaini. This solution did the work. And indeed, @u_mulder, `strnatcasecmp` looks more elegent. :)